# Can I build FileCheck and Not in llvm independently?

Tags: llvm

When I build klee-2.3,it hint me that there are no `FileCheck` and `not` in dir `${LLVM_DIR}$/bin`, the LLVM I use is directly downloaded release instead of built from.

So I check that there are `FileCheck` and `not` in dir `llvm-project/llvm/utils`. And there is only one cpp file in `FileCheck` and `not`

- so could I simply build the cpps into executable file `FileCheck` and `not` instead of build with LLVM because it is very time-consuming?
- if I could, how do I modify cmakelist.txt?